# Detecting the actual completion of programmatic deployment in JBoss 7.1.x

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I'm developing an app that performs programmatic deployment of EJBs in JBoss 7.1.x. Here's the code snippet:

```
// connect
CommandContext cmdCtx = 
  CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext(...);
cmdCtx.connectController();
ModelControllerClient ctrlClient = cmdCtx.getModelControllerClient();
// deploy
String command = 
  String.format("deploy \"%s\" --name=%s --server-groups=%s", path, name, group);
ModelNode request = cmdCtx.buildRequest(command);
ctrlClient.execute(request);
```

Now, how can I determine the deployment has actually completed? The call to `ctrlClient.execute(request)` returns almost immediately, but the server continues to process the deployment for some time. I need to know when it's actually done, and maybe even if it succeeded or not.

One idea I have is to write my own logging appender, and look for some predefined messages, but is there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the CLI API try the `org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.DeploymentPlan` or `org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.domain.DeploymentPlan` API's. You can see an example of this in the [maven-plugin](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/plugin/deployment/domain/DomainDeployment.java) source. (Note this is the domain one as it appears you're deploying to a domain server)